# Angular custom/delayed Lazy PreloadingStrategy bug

Tags: angular, rxjs, lazy-loading

I can't understand why my preloading strategy is registered and loaded multiple times even after modules are already loaded ...

Standard `PreloadAllModules` from Angular source is :

```
export class PreloadAllModules implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, fn: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
        console.log('registering preload', route.path);
        function test() {
            console.log('preloading', route.path);
            return fn();
        }
        return _catch.call(test(), () => of(null));
    }
}
```

Here, both console.log will trigger only once for each of my lazy-routes, enfin if I navigate around my lazy-routes, it won't never re-run (normal).

My custom strategy, where I try to add a minimim delay to it :

```
export class PreloadAllModulesWithDelay implements PreloadingStrategy {
    preload(route: Route, fn: () => Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
        console.log('registering preload', route.path);
        return timer(5000).pipe(
            first(),
            map(() => {
                console.log('preloading', route.path);
                return _catch.call(fn(), () => of(null));
            })
        );
    }
}
```

Here, at first, the `registering` logs will be called, then 5s after the `loading` will be called, as intended. But after several routes change, the registering/loading will re-run, as if angular didn't save the modules conf.

Tried to debug angular core source without success.

Note: for those wondering, I'm creating this delayed strategy because angular lazy loads modules too quickly... it load them while my router animation is still performing and this results in a UI freeze for a few milliseconds (that breaks the fluidity of my animation).. That may be an angular bug.

Comment: change map(...) to switchMap(...)

Comment: @Miller Thanks that was it. Post that as an answer and i'll gladly give you the bounty

Comment: Done. Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `map` is returning a new inner Observable that angular doesn't know what to do with.

You should instead use `switchMap` or `flatMap` to flatten this out.